# 2D Camera panning in SharpDX

Tags: c#, wpf, direct2d, sharpdx

I am new to DirectX and Direct3D/2D etc and just currently running an experiment on whether to pursue making a cad viewer for a machine we have.

I am using the control from here [Direct2dOnWPF](https://github.com/mbrenn/direct2donwpf) to enable me to display Direct2D onto WPF window using SharpDX.

At the moment I have the control working and its loads a file and displays a drawing.

I have now created a camera and I have implemented zooming (to a degree) but my issue is with panning. The issue is that when panning I expect the drawing to move with the mouse but it doesn't. Small movements it kind of does but bigger movements cause the drawing to move beyond the mouse movement. Almost like the further I move the mouse in a single movement, the faster it moves.

Ok some code, the Direct2DControl is based on an Image control so I have access to mouse events etc. Here is the some of code on the control with mouse events and a timer. I tried a timer to detect when the mouse stopped as I found the panning would not stop when the mouse did.

```
// Timer to detect mouse stop
private Timer tmr;

public Direct2dControl()
   {
        //
        // .... Init stuff
        //

        // Mouse panning

        // get mouse position
        MouseOrigin = CurrentMousePosition = new Point(0, 0);

        tmr = new Timer { Interval = 50 };
        tmr.Elapsed += Tmr_Elapsed;
   }

protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

        if (!DragIsOn)
        {
            DragIsOn = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);

        if (DragIsOn)
        {
            DragIsOn = false;
            DragStarted = false;
            MouseOrigin = CurrentMousePosition = e.GetPosition(this);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        if (!DragIsOn) return;

        MouseMoved = true;

        if (!DragStarted)
        {
            DragStarted = true;
            MouseOrigin = CurrentMousePosition = e.GetPosition(this);

            tmr.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentMousePosition = e.GetPosition(this);

            var x = (float)(MouseOrigin.X - CurrentMousePosition.X);
            var y = (float) (MouseOrigin.Y - CurrentMousePosition.Y);

            cam.MoveCamera(cam.ScreenToWorld(new Vector2(x, y)));

            tmr.Stop();
            tmr.Start();
        }
    }

private void Tmr_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseOrigin = CurrentMousePosition;

        tmr.Stop();
        MouseMoved = false;
    }
```

and the panning in camera class by moving the position.

```
public void MoveCamera(Vector2 cameraMovement)
    {
        Vector2 newPosition = Position + cameraMovement;

        Position = newPosition;
    }

    public Matrix3x2 GetTransform3x2()
    {
        return TransformMatrix3x2;
    }

    private Matrix3x2 TransformMatrix3x2
    {
        get
        {
            return
                Matrix3x2.Translation(new Vector2(-Position.X, -Position.Y)) *
                Matrix3x2.Rotation(Rotation) *
                Matrix3x2.Scaling(Zoom) *
                Matrix3x2.Translation(new Vector2(Bounds.Width * 0.5f, Bounds.Height * 0.5f));
        }
    }
```

and finally at the start of the begin rendering I update the RenderTarget Transform

```
target.Transform = cam.GetTransform3x2();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're calculating the coordinates wrong. First, you need to set the MouseOrigin variable in OnLeftMouseButtonDown and don't modify it in any other method:

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

    if (!DragIsOn)
    {
        DragIsOn = true;
        MouseOrigin = e.GetPosition(this);

        // I don't know the type of your cam variable so the following is pseudo code
        MouseOrigin.x -= cam.CurrentPosition.x;
        MouseOrigin.y -= cam.CurrentPosition.y;
    }
}
```

And modify OnMouseMove like this:

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseMove(e);

    if (!DragIsOn) return;

    MouseMoved = true;

    var x = (float)(e.GetPosition(this).x - MouseOrigin.X);
    var y = (float) (e.GetPosition(this).y - MouseOrigin.Y);

    cam.MoveCamera(cam.ScreenToWorld(new Vector2(x, y)));

    tmr.Stop();
    tmr.Start();

}
```

The DragStarted and CurrentMousePosition variables are not needed.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for this. The panning speed now seems right but there now seems to be an issue with the direction it moves in. If i click and drag from center to the bottom right, the objects move up to the top left. If i then stop and then click and drag and move the mouse up,  the objects continues to move in its original path to the top left but then it moves down. If I then stop and then click and drag to move left across the screen the object goes back to the top left.

Comment: What's the type of your `cam` variable?

Comment: oh the type cam is just my Camera class.

Comment: Hmm well sorry don't know what else could be wrong then

Comment: I got it working, I changed this 'cam.MoveCamera(cam.ScreenToWorld(new Vector2(x, y)));' to this 'cam.MoveCamera(cam.ScreenToWorld(new Vector2(-x, -y)));' to get everything moving in the right direction.
Underneath that line and before `tmr.Stop' I reset the mouse origin like this. `MouseOrigin = e.GetPosition(this);`.
Finally, I removed your 2 lines in `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` for setting the X and Y of the mouse origin with the camera position. Work perfect.